# How to say sentences like : the less this, the less that/the less this, the more that/

Tags: grammar

How to say in Korean sentences like : 
-The less he eats, the less he drinks.
-The less he is fat, the less he is small.

-The less he eats, the more he drinks.
-The less he is fat, the more he is small.

-The more he eats, the less he drinks.
-The more he is fat, the less he is small.

-The more he eats, the more he drinks.
-The more he is fat, the more he is small.

Comment: At least in the "the more...the more" case, the clausal conjunction (으)ㄹ수록 can be used.  I'm not sure, but maybe this can be used to express the "the less..the less" case by somehow negating the verbs?  Anyways, it is a start.  그는 먹을수록 마신다. The more he eats, the more he drinks.

Comment: I ran this through Google and it seems to work:  그는 먹을수록 마시지 않다.  The more he eats, the less he drinks.  but that doesn't mean its right!!  LOL ;-)  Might be understandable at least....let's hope some others chime in on this though, ok?

Comment: Standard conditional statements are usually made with 으면 so you may have to use that to construct the other expressions.  This should mean something like your first sentence, for example. 그는 덜 먹으면 덜 마신다.  As for him, when less eat, less drink.

Answer (score 4):

> The more he eats, the less he drinks.

Above example would be translated to

> 그는 많이 먹을수록 더 적게 마신다.

I guess there are few other candidates that catch certain subtleties but that one seems most appropriate.

*edit*
Clearly I didn't think this through when I posted the answer. Here is (what I think is) an even better translation:

> 그는 많이 먹으면 먹을수록 더 적게 마신다.

Comment: I think it's better to remove "그만큼".  I think "그는 많이 먹을수록 그만큼 적게 마신다" would mean "The more he eats, the less he drinks *by that amount*" (for example, if he eats 500g more, he'll drink 500g less water): it's more specific than the original English sentence.

Comment: @jick That's true.. I was totally over-thinking this. Translation is not exactly my forte I guess haha

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin  Judging by this answer, is it safe to assume it is possible to use (으)ㄹ수록 for all of OP's expressions?  Also, how do the adverbs 적게 and 덜 compare with each other?  That is, why did you use 적게 instead of 덜?

Comment: @B.Alvn Yes, pretty much the same form can be used all of his examples. Also as far as 적게 and 덜 goes, either works, really. To be honest I'm not sure which one is more grammatically correct if we want to be very technical here.

Comment: @B.Alvn in fact I just changed 적게 to 더 적게 because I feel like the former doesn't make any grammatical sense.

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin well, I kind of thought the "more...more" part was already included in ㄹ수록 so I'm not sure why you need to add 더...(?)

Comment: @B.Alvn 많이 먹을수록 and 많이 먹으면 먹을수록 both mean the same thing (eat more). The only difference is that the latter has more emphasis. So 더 before 적게 makes sense in both cases. In other words, 더 is included for the 많게 part but not the 적게 part. Plus, 덜 = 더 적게 anyway, which is what you seem to find correct (don't get me wrong, it *is* correct) based on your examples in other comments.

Comment: I suspect in '더 적게' there is an unconscious influence of 'the less.' I believe the next time Posh_Pumpkin has to say something of this sort, he will say '물은 덜 마신다.' Also it is '마신다' that permits '더 적게.' Suppose the example was, '니가 그러면 그럴수록 나는 니가 더 (덜) 좋아' ('The more you carry on like that, the more (less) I like you'). Here, nobody would say '더 적게 좋아.'  On the other hand, '더 많이 좋아' may be OK. (Also, once someone has said '더 많이 좋아,' the next person can echo the form and get away with saying, 'Well as for me, 더 적게 좋아.') @B.Alvn

Comment: @Catomic spot on, tbf "덜" and "더" tend to sound a little more natural than "더 적게" and "더 많이" in colloquial speech. But in professional writing, I'd definitely use the latter.

Comment: @Catomic Don't worry about me, I'm simply not going to use 적게 ....ever, I don't even like the sound of that word, quite frankly!  (ㅋㅋ)